# Cannot create an organization-owned private repository when logged in to my personal account on Github Desktop

Tags: github, github-desktop

My personal GitHub account is a member of an organization account which can create private repositories, and of which I am also an owner (but with a different username). I am trying to create a private repo while logged in from GitHub Desktop while logged in to my personal account. However, the private repository option is disabled, even after I choose the organization as the owner, as shown below.

[image]

So I have to log in to the organization account before the private option is enabled.

[image]

I can create a private repo normally from a browser, however.

[image]

Other following operations (e.g. commits) seem to be fine once I get the write permission.

So do I miss a step here? Or is this intentionally disabled in GitHub desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering [organizations](https://help.github.com/articles/about-organizations/) only proposes private repos under a paid plan, maybe your personal account is not associated with a private account, while your other account owner of the organization is.

The web interface might have (on GitHub side) all the information to link the two accounts, but GitHub Desktop might not (locally) have that same information and might lack the API to query it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer VonC. I can create a private repo with my personal account using the web interface, so I guess it has been properly associated with the organization. Probably it has something to do with the Desktop client itself, as written in your second paragraph. I will take it as the answer.